# What are the region codes for app engine URLs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dns

Since [2020](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#region-id), App Engine apps are served at  `[PROJECT].[REGION].r.appspot.com`.

> Once your app is running in App Engine, you can use the following URL to send HTTP requests to the app:
> https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com
> where PROJECT_ID is the ID of the Google Cloud project that contains the app.

I think this is part of GCP moving internal DNS from [global to regional](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#instance-fully-qualified-domain-names).

The same reference says:

> The REGION_ID is an abbreviated code that Google assigns based on the region you select when you create your app. The code does not correspond to a country or province, even though some region IDs may appear similar to commonly used country and province codes. For apps created after February 2020, REGION_ID.r is included in App Engine URLs. For existing apps created before this date, the region ID is optional in the URL.

Empirically, I can see that [REGION] resolves to 'ts' for an app deployed in australia-southeast1, but 'ey' for an app in europe-west3.

How can I derive what URL my app is going to deploy too in any region?

Comment: FYI: us-east4 shows up as `{PROJECT_ID|.uk.r.appspot.com` on my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gcloud CLI. Execute the command

`gcloud app describe --project=<PROJECT_ID>`

One of the attributes returned is `defaultHostname` and it will have a value with format

`[PROJECT].[REGION].r.appspot.com`

Comment: Thanks. Does that command only work after deploying an app to the region? I am looking for a way to preconfigure my deployment pipeline before deploying the app.

Comment: Before you deploy your app, you need to have created it already in Google Cloud either via the console UI or via gcloud CLI. Once the project has been created in Google Cloud, you can run the above command. This means you can run it before your first deployment.

Comment: OK. I was hoping for some sort of lookup or reference so I could set up the links to the service url in a pipeline before deploying to a project. As I understand, app engine can only be created once and the region is fixed for the project. So we will have to hand code these for each environment.